# ST3: How to use a plugin's commands in a macro?

Tags: python, macros, sublimetext, sublimetext3

In Sublime Text 3, I want to create a macro that pastes the current file's "Relative Path From Project, Encoded", which is a command supplied by the excellent [Sidebar Enhancements](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements).

I've activated console logging to follow my experiments:

- open the console (`` Ctrl-` ``)
- `sublime.log_commands(True)`.

When I perform the actions I want to capture, I see in the console:

```
command: side_bar_copy_path_absolute_from_project_encoded
command: paste
```

however when I record the actions, the json produced on save is:

```
[
    {
        "args": null,
        "command": "paste"
    }
]
```

If I hack the macro manually (taking my cue for args from the [Unofficial Sublime Docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/macros.html) and [SideBarEnhancements / Side Bar.sublime-menu](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements/blob/st3/Side%20Bar.sublime-menu)) :

```
[
    { "command": "side_bar_copy_path_relative_from_project_encoded", "args": {"paths": []} },
    { "command": "paste", "args": null  }
]
```

…then playback the macro, I see the following in the console:

```
Unknown macro command side_bar_copy_path_relative_from_project_encoded
```

(I also tried `null` as an arg for `side_bar_copy_path_relative_from_project_encoded`).

Do I need to reference the package or classname in my macro command? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Yeeha! figured it out - I believe macros may not support all commands, so I tried a plugin:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

'''
    Paste the current file's Relative Path From Project (Encoded).
    Requires https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements to be installed

    First save this file as:
    ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/paste-path.py

    More details about writing plugins:
    http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/plugins.html

    To trigger the command with 'Command Option Shift p',
    add the following to your Sublime Text > Preferences > Keybindings - User

    [
        { "keys": ["super+option+shift+p"], "command": "paste_path"}
    ]
'''

class PastePathCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        self.window.run_command("side_bar_copy_path_relative_from_project_encoded", {"paths": []})
        self.window.run_command("paste")
```

Here it is as a gist: https://gist.github.com/9505770

---

Edit: Sorry, incomplete info! You need to save this file as something like:

`~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/paste-path.py`

More information: https://docs.sublimetext.io/reference/plugins.html

Comment: ST macros only support Text Commands. I made a few fixes to a plugin someone had posted on the ST forum to run any type of command. See https://github.com/skuroda/ImprovedMacros/blob/master/improved_macros/run_multiple_commands.py for details. My original intention was to build something to replace the default macro functionality, but hadn't found a good way to capture all keys, commands, etc.

Comment: I really want this but when I copy the command you provided into my Keybindings - User file, it doesn't work.  What is up with the code `import sublime, sublime plugin` before and the `class` getting called at the end?

Comment: Sorry, I left out some salient details! This is Edited my answer…

Comment: oops, took too long, can't edit my comment: 

…this is a plugin, rather than a keybinding, preference, snippet, command, or macro. Sublime is written in python; `run_command()` is a function defined in sublime or sublime_plugin, hence those (functions? classes?) being included up top. I'm no expert, but it works for me :) Good luck! (Edited my answer)